# Loop blocks DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom, dom-manipulation

I have a simple counting loop that counts to 10000 and logs every number to the console. Before i start the loop i want to write "TEST" to the body in my html.
Although i do this before i start the loop it appends "TEST" to the body only after the loop is done. However i can log something to the console before starting the loop. I think i am blocking the browser thread or something, i don't know how to write this in a non blocking manner. I have been trying to figure out this Problem for quite some time. Your Help would be much appreciated !!!

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myfunc()">click me</button>

</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

My javascript code:

```
function myfunc() {
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1").innerText = "TEST"
    document.body.appendChild(h1) //appends only after loop is done
    console.log("test") // this works
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to put your loop code in a `timeout` and set the delay to 1 millisecond

```js
function myfunc() {
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1")
    h1.innerText = "TEST"
    document.body.appendChild(h1) //appends before the loop
    console.log("test") // this works
    setTimeout(()=>{
      for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
          console.log(i)
      }
    },1)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myfunc()">click me</button>

</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a small addition: A timeout of `0` would also work as this still places the call in the queue of the event loop. `0` does not mean instant invocation.